# Is it possible to bind more than one domain to a website provided both domains point to the same IP address?

Tags: iis, iis-10

I had an old website called `action.rpg.games.org` that I shutdown on an old server.

I started a new IIS website on Windows Server 2016 with a simpler domain name: `collection.games.org`. It's working fine.

I want to redirect all traffic that is trying to hit `action.rpg.games.org` to the new domain name of `collection.games.org`.

So I changed my DNS entry for `action.rpg.games.org` to point to the IP address of the new server.

On the new server, I simply edited the bindings for the new website so that the bindings now contain both `action.rpg.games.org` and `collection.games.org` on both port **80** and port **443** ( got SSL certs for both).

But when I do that last step of adding the old domain to the new website bindings, both old and new domain stop working.  If I delete the old, so that only the new is there, it works fine with the new domain.

Here is the binding information from the IIS configuration file:

```
    <site name="GameRepo" id="2" serverAutoStart="true">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="GameRepo">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\GameRepo" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:collection.games.org" />
            <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:collection.games.org" sslFlags="0" />
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:action.rpg.games.org" />
            <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:action.rpg.games.org" sslFlags="1" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
```

Is there any trick to getting this to work?

THanks!

Comment: What URLs in "both old and new URLs stop working"? Please make sure you edit the question and include the exact information. Also when you created HTTPS site bindings, did you enable SNI? A question without important details cannot be answered. You are using IIS 10 (part of Windows Server 2016), so iis-7 is also inappropriate.

Comment: @LexLi I'm sorry, that was confusing.  I changed URL to domain because that's what I was thinking in my head.   Thanks!

Comment: If you cannot understand what I said above, you might consider reading more about IIS site bindings https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html By sharing the exact XML elements from IIS configuration file (or the diagnostics report), you can help others learn how you configured the site. That's essential to learn what's wrong here.

Comment: As lex says, we should know what you mean about now working. Face the 404 error when using `action.rpg.games.org` and `collection.games.org`. I suggest you could also delete the HTTPS setting to try again.

Comment: @BrandoZhang deleting the HTTPS settings and trying again worked! Thanks !@

Comment: I guess maybe there are some temp setting causing this issue.  I'm glad to hear you have solved the issue.